# Android Ignores Content-Disposition: Attachment Inside Iframe

Tags: android, html, http, http-headers

I have a link to a download handler inside an iframe. This download handler has "Content-Disposition: Attachment" in the headers to force the user to download the file. This works in every browser *except* on Android devices. Android ignores the file without any errors or messages. Using Fiddler, i can confirm that the handler is getting requested successfully, & the download appears to complete successfully, but the browser is not letting me save or open the file.

Before you tell me to stop using iframes, i am afraid that is not an option for me at this time.

Below is some code to reproduce this issue. Three files:

1. Default.aspx: Contains an iframe pointing to DownloadPage.aspx
2. DownloadPage.aspx: Contains a hyperpink to Download.ashx
3. Download.ashx: Responds with a text/plain content-type type with content-disposition: attachment

Default.aspx:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="AndroidTest.Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <iframe src="DownloadPage.aspx" width="320" height="1000"></iframe>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

DownloadPage.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="DownloadPage.aspx.cs" Inherits="AndroidTest.DownloadPage" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:HyperLink NavigateUrl="~/Download.ashx" runat="server">Download</asp:HyperLink>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Download.ashx.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace AndroidTest {
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for Download
    /// </summary>
    public class Download : IHttpHandler {

        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) {
            context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
            context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=\"test.txt\"");
            context.Response.Write("Hello World");
        }

        public bool IsReusable {
            get {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

most browsers will do this as a point of security to avoid maliciously embedded automated downloads. you may want to present the user with a link or a button to complete the download so that the browser recognises the interaction and allows the download to complete.